# How to remove channel-specific notification from Slack?

Tags: notifications, slack

I have added a channel-specific notification for `#general` in a Slack workspace. But now, I want to remove the channel-specific notification for `#general` so that it gets the default notification setting (i.e., the workspace notification setting). I am looking for an option on the Slack web app. I have also looked for it on the Android app. But there are no options. For example, for every channel, there are only three options:

- *All new messages*
- *Direct messages, mentions & keywords*
- *Nothing*.

But there is no option for default. How can I set the channel notification to default (i.e., the workspace notification setting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset your channel preferences back to default, you'll need to go to your workspace preferences. In the 'notifications' section, go to the bottom of the page. Here you can find the channels which are using channel-specific notifications. Click on the cross icon (x) right next to the channel you are interested in, and it'll be set back to default.

For reference, you can see the screenshot below.

[image: Slack Workspace Preferences]

Comment: This is away down in scrolling! Probably could be more user-friendly.